# How to fetch all (more than 2000) contacts from Google Contacts using People API

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api

I am working on Google API with Node.js. I need to retrieve all the contacts list from google contacts. There are more than 2000 contacts in the list but the page size limit is 2000,so I am getting only 2000 contacts,using "people.connections.list" method.Can anyone help? How to fetch all contacts?

Comment: You can retrieve the values more than 2000 using [``pageToken``](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list). To use this, please include ``nextPageToken`` to the fields and request it. When the first 2000 values are returned, you can see ``nextPageToken`` in the values. Next, please request it by adding the value of ``nextPageToken`` to the query. By this, you can retrieve the values from 2001. If the values you want are more than 4000, continue this flow. When ``nextPageToken`` is not included in the returned values, it means that the all data are retrieved.

Comment: I am getting the nextPageToken value in the response, if values are more than 2000. Now,how to use that string and get remaining values?

Comment: I'm really sorry for my poor English skill. Next, please request it by adding the value of nextPageToken to the query. By this, you can retrieve the values from 2001. If the values you want are more than 4000, continue this flow. When nextPageToken is not included in the returned values, it means that the all data are retrieved.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it working by using *recursion* and some ES6 features.

The trick is using the `nextPageToken` returned from the previous request in your next request, since [people.connections.list](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list) have a maximum limit of 2000 according to the docs.

```js
const getAllContacts = async (googleApi, current = [], pageToken = undefined) => {
  const { 
    data: { connections, nextPageToken, totalItems } 
  } = await googleApi.connections.list({
    resourceName: 'people/me',
    pageSize: 2000,
    personFields: 'emailAddresses,phoneNumbers', // or whatever personFields you want
    ...(pageToken ? { pageToken } : {})
  });

  // merge contacts from this request with data from your previous requests
  const contacts = [...current, ...connections];

  if (nextPageToken && contacts.length < totalItems) {
    return getAllContacts(googleApi, contacts, nextPageToken);
  }

  return contacts;
}
```

To use this method, make sure that `googleAPI` is an instance of people api as follows

```js
const { people } = google.people({ version: 'v1' });
const contacts = await getAllContacts(people);
```

Answer (score 0):

This was unexpectedly complicated so I'm sharing my solution for others. There is probably a simpler way to do this, but this is how I got it to work. This is javascript ES6 solution.

After trying a bunch of approaches, asynchronous recursion was what ended up working for me.

So here is my basic fetch contacts call:

```
const fetchContacts = _gapi =>
    _gapi.client.people.people.connections
      .list({
        resourceName: 'people/me',
        pageSize: 2000,
        personFields,
      })
      .then(async response => {
        const { connections, nextPageToken } = response.result;
        const contacts = [...connections];

        if (contacts.length >= 2000) {
          await getAllContacts(contacts, nextPageToken, _gapi);
        }

        return contacts;
      }).catch(console.error)
```

In the then block I have a conditional that calls `getAllContacts` if there is more than 2000 contacts.

`getAllContacts` is an asynchronous recursive function that calls `getContacts` as long as there are more contacts to fetch.

```
const getAllContacts = async (_people, _token, _gapi) => {
  if (_people.length < 2000) {
    // terminal case
    const result = await getContacts(_gapi, _token);
    return _people.push(...result.people);
  }

  // block to execute
  const { people, nextPageToken } = await getContacts(_gapi, _token);
  _people.push(...people);
  getAllContacts(people, nextPageToken, _gapi);
};
```

get contacts is just a simple wrapper around the gapi fetch call that returns the contacts and the next page token.

```
const getContacts = (_gapi, _nextPageToken) =>
  _gapi.client.people.people.connections
    .list({
      resourceName: 'people/me',
      pageSize: 2000,
      personFields,
      pageToken: _nextPageToken,
    })
    .then(response => {
      const { connections, nextPageToken } = response.result;
      return { people: connections, nextPageToken };
    });
```

Comment: If you use this, don't forget to fill in `personFields`. So I had a global variable for `const personFields='emailAddresses,names,photos';`

Comment: If there is a simpler/better way to do this, please share.

Answer (score 0):

I found the pageSize has 1000 as limit -> https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list#try-it

So the above suggestions should be applied when contacts are more than 1000.