# Google People API - pageSize getting limit 1000 contacts

Tags: laravel, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

I installed Google People API to get contacts and it works.
The issue is that, despite I applied

```
pageSize => 2000 (this is the max allowed by Google People)
```

I always get maximum 1000 Contacts despite I have 1500 in my Google People. Here my code to get connection into Laravel Controller:

```
        $optParams = array('pageSize' => 2000,'requestMask.includeField' => 'person.phone_numbers,person.names,person.email_addresses');
        $results = $this->people->people_connections->listPeopleConnections('people/me',$optParams);
```

Any help to get all the available contacts?

Thanks!

Comment: I found that pageSize has limit of 1000: https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list#try-it. How to increase?

Comment: This might be able to help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50849556/how-to-fetch-all-more-than-2000-contacts-from-google-contacts-using-people-api

Comment: thanks @JasonE. I saw it already, but not clear how to implement using Laravel Controller. I am not able to add the $results->nextPageToken in the controller